# Return from function is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, return

I am calling function from ajax success and trying to return value from the function

ajax success is

```
  success: function(data)
  { 
    var distance_arr;    
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    { 
        if(data[i].port_name != destination)
        {
            distance_arr = get_port_distance(data[i].port_name,source,type);
            alert(distance_arr);
        }

    }
  }
```

In **get_port_distance**  function I am returning value  as

```
    return  distance;
```

by calculating distance in get_port_distance function. When I alert distance in get_port_distance then it is correct but when I return it It alert blank in ajax success function

```
function get_port_distance(source,destination,type) 
{ 
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();


    var request = 
    {
        origin: source,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [source],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
        var port_distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
        port_distance = port_distance.replace(/\,/g,'').replace(' km',''); // To REMOVE comma(,)
        return  port_distance;

        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: can you please share the code for get_port_distance too as.

Comment: Your looping condition might be giving you blank value. , you might want to break the loop when you get distance value from function

Comment: If you think the problem is in `get_port_distance` function you should post it

Comment: `if(data[i].port_name != destination)` Where `destination`came from, I dont see this variable in your code, also, there is `source`, and `type`. Paste full code for ajax and `get_port_distance`.

Comment: source, type and destination I get it in the function where I called success. I pass them to other function for calculations.   get_port_distance function is too large to post. But I get output correct there. But When I return value it dont get as expected

Comment: Does `get_port_distance()` do anything asynchronous?

Comment: You must paste this function somewhere, like jsfiddle.net. We can't guess where error occurs. Maybe the problem is in some of this variables or other small thing, but without viewing the full source, we can't help you.

Comment: I have posted get_port_distance() in question with required code

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) In your case, `service.getDistanceMatrix()` is asynchronous and that forces `get_port_distance()` to need to be written to work asynchronously as well (in short, that means `return port_distance;` isn't an option).

Answer (score 1):

`return  port_distance;`

is placed inside:

`function (response, status) {}`.

That means that you are not returning anything from:

`function get_port_distance(source,destination,type){}`

See this [Stackflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for help solving the problem returning from an async function.

Comment: Yes. But how I can return it. Now I returned it outside function (response, status) {} it gives error  port_distance is not defined

Comment: Updated answer - see link

Comment: *Yes. But how I can return it.* You cannot return a future or asynchronous value--it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I checked link I am not much familiar with java script. It is hard to understand explanation in the link for me for my code